# Which is correct? "He went to/for America yesterday"

Tags: prepositions

Which is correct?

> 1. He went to America yesterday.
> 2. He went for America yesterday.

I think that 2 is incorrect.
Because the preposition 'for' of 2 sentence isn't appropriate to America.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer here is "He went **to** America".  "To" is used to indicate direction of travel, and so you would usually say "go *to* (a place)" and "come *from* (a place)".

> I went to the coffee shop.
>
> They aren't going to school today.
>
> She never goes to the movies by herself.

However, you should be aware that there are other, idiomatic expressions that use different prepositions with the "to go" verb.  These have [many different meanings](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/go), but if you scroll down the list you will see these definitions:

> ***to go for (something)***: to attack, to try to get, to agree to, to be attracted to, to relate or apply to

some examples of these idioms:

> I could *go for* a sandwich right now (I want to eat a sandwich)
>
> He *went for* Donald Trump in a big way (he was a strong supporter of Donald Trump).
>
> I was so mad I almost *went for* him.  (I almost attacked him).

and many others.